# Is there a Perl equivlant module to pydbg module?

Tags: python, perl

Could someone suggest a Perl module equivlant/or has the most funcionality  of the [pydbg module](http://pedram.redhive.com/PaiMei/docs/PyDbg/) on Python?

Comment: Why do you want to use Perl if you really want to use the Python tool that already does what you need?

Comment: because first i am more aquantied to perl that python and second because i can harness another modules from the cpan.

Answer (score 4):

[The DDD Project](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) is a great front end to the fabulous [Perl Debugger](http://debugger.perl.org/) (mentioned above...)

Answer (score 3):

Have you had a look at the [Perl Debugger](http://debugger.perl.org/)?

**Edit:** Forgot to mention that you might like to get a copy of the "[Perl Debugger Pocket Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005032)" which I found to be more useful than the usual perldoc's.

Comment: Yes I looked but the PYDBG is intended to automate debugging executalbe (like windbg..) and not to debug perl application 
at anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: @donv I think you need to stop using any form of the word "automate" in describing what you want.  We don't understand how you're using it.  Try again without it.